# Sum unique occurrences per night and create a new data frame in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have studied prey deliveries in a breeding owl and want to score the number of prey items delivered during the night to the nestlings. I define night as from 21 to 5. How could I make a new data frame with number of prey each night per location ID based upon these 24/7 observation dataset? In the new data frame, I wish to have the following columns: ID (A & B), No_prey_during_night (the sum of prey items), Time (date, e.g. 4/6 to 5/6), there will be a unique row per night per ID.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y5VCoNWZCmYbyWCktKfMSBqjOIaLeumQ/view?usp=sharing. I have done it in Excel so far, but very time demanding. I would be happy to get help with a simple script I could use in R.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you take a sample of your dataset and provide an example of what the expected output table should look like?

Comment: How is your data initially collected as it sounds that the transcription to record is the time onerous bit. Summaries thereafter are straight forward.

Comment: @RobertoT, I have only tried Excel with pivot table with filter. Very time demanding.

Comment: @Aron, I think I got the solution below from langtang, the output should be similar to that. I will just double check the numbers.

Comment: @Chris, data are from several steps in R. I made the script with some help from collogues some years ago. The data is scored from reviewing video recordings from nests (date and time for each prey delivery). Then I make a data frame in R with the monitoring period (the hours period the cameras have been active), I merge this data frame with the date frame with prey deliveries and each hour are scored with the number of prey deliveries for a given block. Since the owls are nocturnal I'm not that interested in prey deliveries per day, but rather prey deliveries per night.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

read.csv("Tot_prey_example.csv") %>% 

  # create initial datetime variable, `night`
  mutate(night = lubridate::make_datetime(2021, Month,Day,Hour)) %>% 

  # filter to nighttime hours
  filter(Hour>=21 | Hour<=5) %>% 

  # flip datetime variable to the next day if hour is >=21
  mutate(night = if_else(Hour>=21,night + 60*60*24, night)) %>% 

  # now group by the date part of `night`
  group_by(ID,Night_No = as.Date(night)) %>% 

  # summarize the sum of prey
  summarize(
    No_prey_during_night = sum(n),
    No_deliveries_during_night = sum(PreyDelivery)
  ) %>% 

  # replace the Night_No with a character variable showing both dates
  mutate(Night_No = paste0(Night_No-1, "-", Night_No))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 88 × 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
   ID    Night_No              No_prey_during_night No_deliveries_during_night
   <chr> <chr>                                <int>                      <int>
 1 A     2021-06-04-2021-06-05                   12                          5
 2 A     2021-06-05-2021-06-06                   22                          6
 3 A     2021-06-06-2021-06-07                   20                          5
 4 A     2021-06-07-2021-06-08                   14                          6
 5 A     2021-06-08-2021-06-09                   14                          5
 6 A     2021-06-09-2021-06-10                   27                          5
 7 A     2021-06-10-2021-06-11                   22                          4
 8 A     2021-06-11-2021-06-12                   18                          6
 9 A     2021-06-12-2021-06-13                   22                          6
10 A     2021-06-13-2021-06-14                   25                          5
# … with 78 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks,  this solve my question, but I see that I wasn't clear enough in my question, sorry for that. With the script above I get the count for prey during night for a given day,  but I would like to count the number of prey deliveries for a given night. For an nocturnal owl  the hunt starts at "21" and ends the day after at "5". Hence, I have to count the number of prey deliveries at the night between two days. Would that be possible? Like first columns will be named: ID, Night.no, No_prey_during_night. Night.no could be labeled with the two dates 2021-06-04/2021-06-05.

Comment: Sure, see edit where I've associated the evening hours with the subsequent morning hours, by adding one day

Answer (score 0):

To take into account the fact that a night begins and ends on different dates, you could first assign all the morning hours to the prior day. The final label (the `Time` column in your question) then includes the next day. If the year of the data collection has a Feb 29, make sure the year is correct (I used 2022).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

read.csv("Tot_prey_example.csv") %>% 
  mutate(time = make_datetime(year = 2022, month = Month, day = Day, hour = Hour),
         night_time = if_else(between(Hour, 0, 5), time - days(1), time),
         night_date = floor_date(night_time, unit = "day"),
         night = Hour <= 5 | Hour >= 21) %>% 
  filter(night) %>% 
  group_by(ID, night_date) %>% 
  summarise(No_prey_during_night = sum(n), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(next_day = night_date + days(1),
         Time = glue::glue("{day(night_date)}/{month(night_date)} to {day(next_day)}/{month(next_day)}")) %>% 
  select(ID, No_prey_during_night, Time)
#> # A tibble: 88 × 3
#>    ID    No_prey_during_night Time        
#>    <chr>                <int> <glue>      
#>  1 A                       12 4/6 to 5/6  
#>  2 A                       22 5/6 to 6/6  
#>  3 A                       20 6/6 to 7/6  
#>  4 A                       14 7/6 to 8/6  
#>  5 A                       14 8/6 to 9/6  
#>  6 A                       27 9/6 to 10/6 
#>  7 A                       22 10/6 to 11/6
#>  8 A                       18 11/6 to 12/6
#>  9 A                       22 12/6 to 13/6
#> 10 A                       25 13/6 to 14/6
#> # … with 78 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>